# Mysql Replication- Master-bin log files are not updated

Tags: mysql, replication

I am new in Mysql Replication,

My problem is : When i Give SHOW SLAVE STATUS Command on Slave, Master-bin-log files are not updated, i reset it and update the Master-bin-log file with the command CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER , still master-bin-log files are not updated when i check with the SHOW SLAVE STATUS command.

Addition to that, at the appropriate path Master-bin-log files are generated but not updated.

Please help me get out of this problem...

Thanks in advance!!!!

Riddhi

Comment: I would recommend referring to the book 'High Performance MySQL' published by O'Reilly.  That book has a helpful chapter on different replication setups that may help you.

Answer (score 8):

From what you are saying, I assume that you want binary logging on the slave.

I think the problem stems from something that has bitten me many times.

Please add this to /etc/my.cnf on the slave:

```
[mysqld]
log-slave-updates
```

Without this, the data is updated from the relay logs but the transaction is not recorded in the slave's binary logs.

Adding this is crucial, especially if you plan to use the slave as a master someday.